# Data duplicate after join of four tables in Windows Form c# with MS Access

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

I am joining four tables i.e
[image]

users have user_history which workshop he is attending, so as room history where he is staying joining with room is to get name of the room which he is staying

Here is the query that is generate after joining above four tables in Ms Access query Design

```
SELECT
  users.ID,
  users.user_name,
  users.father_name,
  users.phone,
  users.email,
  users.cnic,
  users.address,
  users.user_type,
  users.department,
  users.designation,
  users.emergency_no,
  users.img,
  room_history.ID,
  room_history.room_id,
  room_history.occupant_id,
  room_history.start_date,
  room_history.end_date,
  rooms.room_name,
  user_history.ID,
  user_history.workshop
FROM (users
INNER JOIN (rooms
INNER JOIN room_history
  ON rooms.room_id = room_history.room_id)
  ON users.ID = room_history.occupant_id)
INNER JOIN user_history
  ON users.ID = user_history.user_id;
```

Now the problem is that query works fine, but if user have multiple record in room_history and user_history table it returns four records i.e
[image]

In mysql this duplication is fixed by "GROUP BY" clause, that's not working here
I try to add "GROUP BY" to all fields it still cant work.

Note:

> Üsers.Img data type is ole object so we cant add GROUP BY to it

Here is my query with GROUP BY clause, Still the result is same

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
 users.ID, 
 users.user_name, 
 users.father_name, 
 users.phone, 
 users.email, 
 users.cnic, 
 users.address, 
 users.user_type, 
 users.department, 
 users.designation, 
 users.emergency_no, 
 room_history.ID, 
 room_history.room_id, 
 room_history.occupant_id, 
 room_history.start_date, 
 room_history.end_date, 
 rooms.room_name, 
 user_history.ID, 
 user_history.workshop, 
 user_history.user_id
FROM (users 
 INNER JOIN (rooms INNER JOIN room_history ON rooms.room_id = room_history.room_id) ON users.ID = room_history.occupant_id) 
INNER JOIN user_history ON users.ID = user_history.user_id
GROUP BY 
 users.ID, 
 users.user_name, 
 users.father_name, 
 users.phone, 
 users.email, 
 users.cnic, 
 users.address, 
 users.user_type, 
 users.department, 
 users.designation, 
 users.emergency_no, 
 room_history.ID, 
 room_history.room_id, 
 room_history.occupant_id, 
 room_history.start_date, 
 room_history.end_date, 
 rooms.room_name, 
 user_history.ID, 
 user_history.workshop, 
 user_history.user_id;
```

Comment: when you do a `Group By` you need to have the fields in the select that you are wanting to Group By, please show us your original Group By clause also google what INNER , LEFT , and Right / Outer Joins are and read up on how to do group by there are tons of examples out there. Also read up on how to use `Aliasing` when using joins to make more readable, Google what `DISTINCT` means too this could help clean up your code..

Comment: I add my query with group by clause, you can check

Comment: The use of select distinct / group by in this context, in my opinion, is often a hack for a real solution, which is to find out why there are duplicates.  So the real question, for me, is when you have multiple records in `room_history` which do you want to pull back -- the most recent?  Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes I want to pull most recent records, I am using MS Access

Answer (score 0):

My comment captured part of what I wanted to say, but it's hard to articulate that in a tweet.

In essence, `GROUP BY` and/or `SELECT DISTINCT`, even if they work, are kind of masking the problem.  The problem is that there are four records, and you want to pick one of them.  If there is any distinction in the records, this won't work.  More importantly, I think it's important that when you do this, and you want one record, you specify *which* record you want.

Let's assume, in your example if the `room_history` has multiple records for one occupant/room that you only want the most recent stay.  In that case, assuming your DBMS supports the `with` clause and windowing functions, this would get you that:

```
with most_recent_history as (
  select
    ID, room_id, occupant_id, start_date, end_date,
    max (end_date) over (partition by room_id, occupant_id) as last_date
  from room_history
)
SELECT
  users.ID,
  users.user_name,
  users.father_name,
  users.phone,
  users.email,
  users.cnic,
  users.address,
  users.user_type,
  users.department,
  users.designation,
  users.emergency_no,
  users.img,
  h.ID,
  h.room_id,
  h.occupant_id,
  h.start_date,
  h.end_date,
  rooms.room_name,
  user_history.ID,
  user_history.workshop
FROM
  users
  INNER JOIN rooms
  INNER JOIN most_recent_history h on
    rooms.room_id = h.room_id and
    users.ID = h.occupant_id and
    h.end_date = h.last_date
  INNER JOIN user_history on
    users.ID = h.user_id;
```

If your DBMS does not support windowing functions and/or `with`, there are other ways to do this, but they're a lot more clumsy.  If this is Oracle, SQL Server or PostgreSQL, this will work for sure.

Also, it doesn't seem possible in the real world, but in the event there can be a tie (a person is in two rooms that end on the exact same date), then you can add the tiebreaker to windowing function and use `row_number` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using MS Access, so and/or with is not working. only two users are allowed to stay in the room between 2 dates